# id value as variable vs document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I have a snippet of code here

```html
<div id="pTagId" >some content</div>

<button onclick="console.log(document.getElementById('pTagId').innerHTML);">button1</button>

<button onclick="console.log(pTagId.innerHTML);">button2</button>
```

In the first button I'm using `document.getElementById` to get the tag object.
In the second button I'm directly using `pTagId` without `document.getElementById` and it also works.

is it reliable to use `pTagId` directly without `document.getElementById`? If yes what is the need of `document.getElementById`?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale that is the `id`  of `div` and it prints the tag object.

Comment: I've added `.innerHTML` and created a code snippet out of your sample so people can run the code and see what happens, hope that helps, if you don't like it you can remove it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById()` is the right way to do it.

There are some browsers that make a global variable by the same name as the element id so that may be why it was somehow working, but you should not rely on that.